# How to install BerkeleyDB for Mingw Linux compile environment

Tags: c++, linux, windows, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross-compile an application on Linux using Mingw and am running into the following error message:

```
db.h:14:20: fatal error: db_cxx.h: No such file or directory
```

I understand that this is caused by the Berkeley-DB include files not being present under the Mingw include tree.

My question is: how can I take the Berkeley-DB source files and install them under the Mingw include file tree?

Answer (score 2):

(I'm aware this is an old question - but people might still be searching for a solution to this)

Running Debian 7.6 (wheezy), I checked the file /usr/include/db_cxx.h with the command: `dpkg -S /usr/include/db_cxx.h`

This gave the following response:

```
libdb5.1++-dev: /usr/include/db_cxx.h
```

Then the error message in the question could be fixed by:

```
sudo apt-get install libdb5.1++-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to build db-4.8.30.NC with mingw 4.9.2 32bit try this:

```
../dist/configure --disable-replication --enable-mingw --enable-cxx --prefix=/mingw
make
make install
```